# jQuery prepend element to a href, only once per page

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script that finds any href link with a .jpg or .png as the source, and prepends some extra span elements to link. It works well, however if I have more than one link on a page, the prepend is added multiple times.
For example a page with 3 links, the first a tag will prepend the span 3 times, the second a tag will prepend the span 2 times and the the third link will prepend the span once.
How do I get the span to prepend only once per a tag?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_content_container a[href$='px.jpg'], #main_content_container a[href$='.png']").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('rel','lightbox').addClass("gallerypic");
    $(".gallerypic").prepend("<span><img src='/images/common/zoom_in.png'/></span>");
    $(".gallerypic span").addClass("zoom-icon");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like these two lines don't really belong in your `.each()` block:

```
$(".gallerypic").prepend("<span><img src='/images/common/zoom_in.png'/></span>");
$(".gallerypic span").addClass("zoom-icon");
```

Try moving them after the `.each`, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_content_container a[href$='px.jpg'], #main_content_container a[href$='.png']").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('rel','lightbox').addClass("gallerypic");
    });

    $(".gallerypic").prepend("<span><img src='/images/common/zoom_in.png'/></span>");
    $(".gallerypic span").addClass("zoom-icon");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you are looping through the matched elements but then you use the class "gallerypic" to prepend and that matches them all again. Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_content_container a[href$='px.jpg'], #main_content_container a[href$='.png']").each(function() {
         $(this).attr('rel','lightbox').addClass("gallerypic");
         $(this).attr('rel','lightbox').prepend("<span class='zoom-icon'><img src='/images/common/zoom_in.png'/></span>");
    });
});
```